# Is there a way to prevent OSX from polluting my projects with thousands of .DS_Store files?

Tags: macos, configuration

I really want to get rid of them. I keep removing these files and they always come back at some point. I understand that OSX wants to keep the organisation of folders in memory, but if I could deactivate this behavior it would be awesome.

Comment: macOS is generally v good but some things they do ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to disable MacOS .DS_Store file creation

Type in terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

**And reboot the Mac**

---

If you want to make this change to all user accounts:

- Option A: manually by executing the same command under their login
- Option B: copy modified com.apple.desktopservices.plist file to the ~/Library/Preferences folder of each other user account

Comment: i've read elsewhere this only applies to `network` drives - is it working for the boot drive?

Comment: It does only apply to network drives, yes

Answer (score 4):

**Is there a way to prevent OSX (now macOS) from creating `.DS_Store` files?** Barely.

There have been a couple of tools to deal with this over the years. The one that stands out most in my mind is [Asepsis](https://asepsis.binaryage.com/) because the author has been vocal about the problem as well as the entire journey up to stopping delevopment.

Apple is clearly uncomfortable with users trying to prevent `.DS_Store` files however, and after System Integrity Protection (and some other restrictions) came in it became much harder to make a tool, much harder for people to be comfortable installing it, and much much harder to keep it up to date with each version of OSX.

Apple is clearly of the strong opinion that `.DS_Store` files are vital to the user enjoyment. As of 10.4 those files also started storing some Spotlight metadata so Apple had relied on them for even more than "just" icon placements.

As of macOS Sierra they even force-hid those files from Finder. Now when you enable "show all hidden files" it will still not show `.DS_Store` files.

Personally, I view all folders in detail mode and don't use tags so I genuinely have no use for the `.DS_Store` files.

**Is there a way to get rid of them?** Yes. Many, infact. You can even automate it.

Here's a way you can delete them from Terminal:

`find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

*Note: change it to `find /name_of_folder_to_search -name...` in order to delete `.DS_Store` files from other folders, and `sudo find /Volumes -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete` to delete them from every filesystem your mac has access to.*

To automate this you can use `cron` with a line such as

`0 * * * * find /Volumes -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

**And, two bonuses:**

1. If your system has "show hidden files" enabled but you don't want to see them on your desktop, check out another answer I wrote: https://superuser.com/a/950897/191730
2. There are other hidden files too! "AppleDouble" is a common type that actually has it's own cleanup tool built in to macOS: `dot_clean`

Comment: spent the last few hours trying to figure out why my zip file is not accepted in the work form and it comes to osx adding garbage .ds_store to the zip... finally found after running zip -x and yes finder doesn't show them